# mongodb switches from primary state to secondary during script

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb replicaset setup using [bitnami/helm](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb)  which lives on my k8 cluster.

I have a cron job that runs every night to store data in a my mongo db. It often fails when it tries to connect to mongo because mongo is no longer in a primary state.

> MongoError: Not primary while writing

When i check the logs of the mongodb arbiter i can see the following logs around the same time.

`kubectl logs -f mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-0`

First i get a set of logs like this which tell me slow query or the server status was slow.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:19:19.376+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"replSetHeartbeat":"rs0","configVersion":492521,"hbv":1,"from":"<redacted>6-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017","fromId":0,"term":14,"$replData":1,"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1605583150,"i":1}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"GGP8UlQZ1+TrxWk2hronxraFYrU=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":6855964983600087045}},"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":489,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":3476}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:19:21.251+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20499,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"serverStatus was very slow","attr":{"timeStats":{"after basic":1279,"after asserts":1287,"after connections":1288,"after electionMetrics":1690,"after extra_info":1690,"after flowControl":1690,"after globalLock":1690,"after locks":1691,"after logicalSessionRecordCache":1710,"after mirroredReads":1712,"after network":1712,"after opLatencies":1723,"after opReadConcernCounters":1723,"after opcounters":1723,"after opcountersRepl":1723,"after oplogTruncation":1756,"after repl":5239,"after security":5579,"after storageEngine":7089,"after tcmalloc":7089,"after trafficRecording":7089,"after transactions":7089,"after transportSecurity":7089,"after twoPhaseCommitCoordinator":7089,"after wiredTiger":7101,"at end":7118}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:19:23.436+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20499,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"serverStatus was very slow","attr":{"timeStats":{"after basic":17,"after asserts":17,"after connections":17,"after electionMetrics":17,"after extra_info":17,"after flowControl":17,"after globalLock":17,"after locks":17,"after logicalSessionRecordCache":17,"after mirroredReads":17,"after network":338,"after opLatencies":354,"after opReadConcernCounters":398,"after opcounters":398,"after opcountersRepl":398,"after oplogTruncation":576,"after repl":697,"after security":707,"after storageEngine":810,"after tcmalloc":1015,"after trafficRecording":1028,"after transactions":1038,"after transportSecurity":1038,"after twoPhaseCommitCoordinator":1065,"after wiredTiger":1075,"at end":1113}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:19:26.085+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"replSetHeartbeat":"rs0","configVersion":492521,"hbv":1,"from":"<redacted>6-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017","fromId":0,"term":14,"$replData":1,"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1605583163,"i":2}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"r6eVme2iBLtlxWnwJyYhawoEin4=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":6855964983600087045}},"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":489,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":149}}
```

Then eventually the member switches to `secondary` state

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:22:18.507+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn7501","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"100.96.4.176:38788","client":"conn7501","doc":{"driver":{"name":"NetworkInterfaceTL","version":"4.4.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"PRETTY_NAME=\"Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)\"","architecture":"x86_64","version":"Kernel 4.9.0-11-amd64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:22:18.508+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn7500","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"__system","authenticationDatabase":"local","client":"100.96.4.176:38784"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:22:18.550+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn7501","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"__system","authenticationDatabase":"local","client":"100.96.4.176:38788"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:22:20.175+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21215,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-40","msg":"Member is in new state","attr":{"hostAndPort":"<redacted>-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017","newState":"SECONDARY"}}
```

Not always but this time it seemed to have recovered and gone back into primary state

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:22:28.913+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ELECTION", "id":23980,   "ctx":"conn7499","msg":"Responding to vote request","attr":{"request":"{ replSetRequestVotes: 1, setName: \"rs0\", dryRun: true, term: 14, candidateIndex: 0, configVersion: 492521, configTerm: -1, lastCommittedOp: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 } }","response":"{ term: 14, voteGranted: true, reason: \"\" }","replicaSetStatus":"Current replSetGetStatus output: { set: \"rs0\", date: new Date(1605583348912), myState: 7, term: 14, syncSourceHost: \"\", syncSourceId: -1, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, majorityVoteCount: 2, writeMajorityCount: 1, votingMembersCount: 2, writableVotingMembersCount: 1, optimes: { lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, lastCommittedWallTime: new Date(1605583310813), appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(0, 0), t: -1 }, lastAppliedWallTime: new Date(1605583310813), lastDurableWallTime: new Date(0) }, members: [ { _id: 0, name: \"<redacted>-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017\", health: 1.0, state: 2, stateStr: \"SECONDARY\", uptime: 37487, optime: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, optimeDate: new Date(1605583310000), optimeDurableDate: new Date(1605583310000), lastHeartbeat: new Date(1605583348185), lastHeartbeatRecv: new Date(1605583348696), pingMs: 277, lastHeartbeatMessage: \"\", syncSourceHost: \"\", syncSourceId: -1, infoMessage: \"\", configVersion: 492521, configTerm: -1 }, { _id: 1, name: \"mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-0.mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017\", health: 1.0, state: 7, stateStr: \"ARBITER\", uptime: 0, syncSourceHost: \"\", syncSourceId: -1, infoMessage: \"\", configVersion: 492521, configTerm: -1, self: true, lastHeartbeatMessage: \"\" } ] }"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:22:28.918+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ELECTION", "id":23980,   "ctx":"conn7499","msg":"Responding to vote request","attr":{"request":"{ replSetRequestVotes: 1, setName: \"rs0\", dryRun: false, term: 15, candidateIndex: 0, configVersion: 492521, configTerm: -1, lastCommittedOp: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 } }","response":"{ term: 15, voteGranted: true, reason: \"\" }","replicaSetStatus":"Current replSetGetStatus output: { set: \"rs0\", date: new Date(1605583348918), myState: 7, term: 15, syncSourceHost: \"\", syncSourceId: -1, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, majorityVoteCount: 2, writeMajorityCount: 1, votingMembersCount: 2, writableVotingMembersCount: 1, optimes: { lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, lastCommittedWallTime: new Date(1605583310813), appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(0, 0), t: -1 }, lastAppliedWallTime: new Date(1605583310813), lastDurableWallTime: new Date(0) }, members: [ { _id: 0, name: \"<redacted>-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017\", health: 1.0, state: 2, stateStr: \"SECONDARY\", uptime: 37487, optime: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp(1605583310, 7), t: 14 }, optimeDate: new Date(1605583310000), optimeDurableDate: new Date(1605583310000), lastHeartbeat: new Date(1605583348185), lastHeartbeatRecv: new Date(1605583348696), pingMs: 277, lastHeartbeatMessage: \"\", syncSourceHost: \"\", syncSourceId: -1, infoMessage: \"\", configVersion: 492521, configTerm: -1 }, { _id: 1, name: \"mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-0.mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017\", health: 1.0, state: 7, stateStr: \"ARBITER\", uptime: 0, syncSourceHost: \"\", syncSourceId: -1, infoMessage: \"\", configVersion: 492521, configTerm: -1, self: true, lastHeartbeatMessage: \"\" } ] }"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:22:30.187+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21215,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-40","msg":"Member is in new state","attr":{"hostAndPort":"<redacted>-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017","newState":"PRIMARY"}}

{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-17T03:23:29.463+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21216,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-40","msg":"Member is now in state RS_DOWN","attr":{"hostAndPort":"<redacted>-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017","heartbeatMessage":"Request 18699 timed out, deadline was 2020-11-17T03:23:13.293+00:00, op was RemoteCommand 18699 -- target:[<redacted>-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017] db:admin expDate:2020-11-17T03:23:13.285+00:00 cmd:{ replSetHeartbeat: \"rs0\", configVersion: 492521, hbv: 1, from: \"mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-0.mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017\", fromId: 1, term: 15 }"}}
```

**rs.status()**

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:33.966Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(16),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 1,
    "votingMembersCount" : 2,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 1,
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1605603211, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        },
        "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:31.190Z"),
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1605603211, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:31.190Z"),
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1605603211, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1605603211, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        },
        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:31.190Z"),
        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:31.190Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1605603191, 1),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
        "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
        "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2020-11-17T03:24:18.778Z"),
        "electionTerm" : NumberLong(16),
        "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1605583378, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(15)
        },
        "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1605583393, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(15)
        },
        "numVotesNeeded" : 2,
        "priorityAtElection" : 5,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
        "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
        "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2020-11-17T03:24:18.784Z"),
        "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2020-11-17T03:24:18.868Z")
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "<redacted>-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 57390,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1605603211, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(16)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:31Z"),
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1605583458, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2020-11-17T03:24:18Z"),
            "configVersion" : 492521,
            "configTerm" : -1,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-0.mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 19766,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:33.072Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2020-11-17T08:53:33.078Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 492521,
            "configTerm" : -1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1605603211, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"nSv0QPiJ+uvO9A8ljcDIpICTHqg="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6855964983600087045")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1605603211, 1)
}
```

Can someone help me understand what is happening here and what i can do to fix it.

Comment: you should have atleast `3 nodes` for replica set to ensure the high availability. Try to add another secondary node to the same replica you might not face this same issue.